# Is there a way to write a batch file to rename a file using a set variable?

Tags: batch-file, variables, rename

I am trying to create a batch file that makes folders and places files in these folders. I have accomplished that but I want to now rename the file to a set variable (the name of the project)

I have tried the rename function.

```
@echo off
SET x="Project Name"
md %x%\"Bid Proposals"
md %x%\"Reports"
md %x%\"Drawings"
md %x%\"Specifications"
md %x%\"Addendums"
cd /d  K:\ESTIMATING\2019 ESTIMATING\2019 BID-PROPOSALS\%x%\Bid Proposals
copy "filelocation\Bid Proposal - Template.docx" 
rename "Bid Proposal - Template" "%x% - Bid Proposal"
```

I would like it to rename the file to the project name using the variable.

It copies and places the file but doesn't rename it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many quotes.

Try

```dos
@echo off
SET "pname=Project Name"
for %%a in ("Bid Proposals" "Reports" "Drawings" "Specifications"
 "Addendums") do md "%pname%\%%~a"
cd /d  K:\ESTIMATING\2019 ESTIMATING\2019 BID-PROPOSALS\%pname%\Bid Proposals
copy "filelocation\Bid Proposal - Template.docx" .
rename "Bid Proposal - Template" "%pname% - Bid Proposal"
```

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

I've changed `x` to something more meaningful.

The `for` assigns each *[in this case, quoted]* value to `%%a` in turn. The `%%~a` removes the quotes from `%%a`.

I believe the `copy` will require a destination. I've added `.` which means `the current directory`, so the file `"filelocation\Bid Proposal - Template.docx"` should be copied to the current directory as `"Bid Proposal - Template.docx"`

The `rename` will match the filenames, so the *from* name should probably be `"Bid Proposal - Template.docx" and the *to* name "%pname% - Bid Proposal.docx"

And I believe the plural of `Addendum` is probably `Addenda`.

Comment: I copied your suggestion, this is now a more efficient way of doing it. the rename is still not working....also you are correct with the addendums/addenda

Comment: Thanks!!! I just added the file extensions and it solved the renaming issue. Also I have less than the 15 reputation but I did upvote this!

Comment: with `copy`, the destination is optional. If there is no destination given, it defaults to the current working folder (although explicitly giving it the current working folder with `.` doesn't hurt)

Comment: If I understand this task correctly, I don't see a reason to copy the file, then rename it as two separate instructions. I'd therefore remove the last line and change the line above it to, `Copy /Y "filelocation\Bid Proposal - Template.docx" "%x% - Bid Proposal.docx"`.